# How do I sort and use multiple files in a bash script?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, filenames

I have multiple pairs of files that differ only in one number:

121_S11_L001_R1_001

121_S11_L001_R2_001

and another pair relative to other files, differ in multiple numbers, but relative to its pair, again only in one number:

120_S10_L001_R1_001

120_S10_L001_R2_001

I have a bash script to process these files individually:

if [ -s $infile ] && [ ! -s $infile.bwa ]; then

```
echo "Creating BWA file..."
time bwa aln $path"Genomeidx" $infile > $infile.bwa
time bwa aln $path"Genomeidx" $infile2 > $infile2.bwa
```

Where 'infile' and 'infile2' are files specified on the command line

Instead of manually typing each pair, how do I recursively select and process each file for each pair?

Comment: Not sure what a pair is. Can you give an example of what you need to type ?

Comment: Each filename, relative to its pair, is identical, except for the R1 and R2. These files are pairs.  I want to process them together as shown in the chunk of bash script, then, another pair similarly.  
Is that what you mean when you say 'what u need to type'?

Comment: I meant is as a reference to your *Instead of manually typing each pair* and would have liked an example since I didn't understand the ones you posted before.

Comment: oh ok.  ./bash.sh filepair1 filepair2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bash globbing to pick out all the `_R1_` style files and then locate its pair.

Something like this could be adapted to do your processing:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_R1_*; do
    pair=${file/_R1_/_R2_}
    if [ -f "$pair" ]; then
        echo "processing $file and its pair $pair"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This does solve the paired problem, but I have been trying to make it run recursively on all paired files.  Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean that the script should descend into subdirectories also?